# Why can't typescript contextually infer these middleware types

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

This code runs exactly as expected, yet typescript doesn't infer the `a` property in the function, any idea why and how to fix it?

```
interface RequestEvent<T extends Record<string, string> = Record<string, string>> {
  params: T
}

interface RequestHandlerOutput {
  body: string
}

type MiddlewareCallback<data> = (event: RequestEvent & data) => Promise<RequestHandlerOutput>

type Middleware<data> = <old>(cb: MiddlewareCallback<data & old>) => MiddlewareCallback<old>

const withA: Middleware<{ a: number }> = cb => async ev => {
  return cb({
    ...ev,
    a: 4,
  })
}

const withB: Middleware<{ b: number }> = cb => async ev => {
  return cb({
    ...ev,
    b: 6,
  })
}
(async () => {
console.log(await withA(withB(async (ev) => {
  // FINE
  ev.b;
  // Not FINE
  ev.a

  return {
    body: `${ev.b} ${ev.a}`
  }
}))({
  params: {}
}))})()
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-dSy6FnCA8rxsPje3Lw2Hw5H1RUIpXe320xpEQMhIUAehzyAAYgBJAByBCFTR5YQA3Ln8yW2N1i2WK0QeXAbNorWzs8KtZEYsgAAYAEjUlbClmQY8rcEsQ6F1ilgzt2j0BmMZjUS8GgylAaAA)

EDIT:
as jcalz pointed out, this is a very difficult problem and simply using a compose function is pretty straight forward. I am fine with other solutions as long as I'm not forced to type out (no pun intended) the previous middleware's types

Comment: Inference doesn't work backwards through multiple function calls like this.  In some sense you are expecting `withB(async (ev) => ({ body: `${ev.b} ${ev.a}` }));` to infer that `ev` is of type with `{a: number}` on it, seemingly from nowhere.  Of course you are actually passing the result of that into `withA()`, but the compiler can't use that information to reach into the call to `withB` and infer stuff.  There might be a way to rewrite things to work, not sure yet. (The more I investigate, the less possible this looks, sorry )

Comment: Please consider using conventional names for type parameters; `data` and `old` look like value names, whereas type parameters are conventionally written as single uppercase letters like `D` and `O`, or sometimes (though I don't recommend this) in UpperPascalCase like `Data` and `Old`.

Comment: Blecch, best I can do here is suggest refactoring to compose your middlewares before calling them, as in [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NdojXw).  Does that address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: No problem, that's kind of what I assumed. at least it prevents me from adding wrong type information.

Yeah I originally did that, but then I thought it would be easier to comprehend with longer names; Noted

Yeah that works! Could you write one with a variadic number of arguments that is recursive? I tried doing it but I failed

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wy44Zm) meet your needs?  I'm happy to write that in my answer but the question as asked doesn't talk about it; could you [edit] the question to at least allude to a possible variadic composition approach?

Comment: Yes! Please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that I can find a canonical source for this, but the compiler just isn't able to perform the kind of inference needed for your formulation to work.  [Contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) of callback parameters tends not to reach backward through *multiple* function calls.  For something like

```
withA(withB(async (ev) => ({ body: "" })));
```

the compiler can infer the type of `ev` contextually from what `withB()` expects, but it cannot do so from what `withA()` expects.  The [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter for `withB()` will be inferred because of the `withA()` call, but it doesn't make it down into the type of `ev`.  So `ev` will have a `b` property but no `a` property, unfortunately.

---

Instead of trying to get that working, I'd suggest refactoring so that you don't have nested function calls.  That could involve composing `withA` and `withB` to something like  `withAB`, and then pass the callback to the composed function.  Here's one way to do it:

```
const comp2 = <T, U>(mwT: Middleware<T>, mwU: Middleware<U>): Middleware<T & U> =>
  cb => mwT(mwU(cb));
const withAB = comp2(withA, withB);
// const withAB: Middleware<{  a: number; } & {  b: number; }>
withAB(async (ev) => ({ body: `${ev.a} ${ev.b}` }));
```

If you want to make the composition function variadic, you can do so (although the compiler won't be able to verify that the implementation satisfies the call signature so you'll need a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or something like it):

```
type IntersectTuple<T extends any[]> =
  { [I in keyof T]: (x: T[I]) => void }[number] extends
  ((x: infer I) => void) ? I : never;

const comp = <T extends any[]>(
  ...middlewares: { [I in keyof T]: Middleware<T[I]> }
): Middleware<IntersectTuple<T>> =>
  cb => middlewares.reduce((a, mw) => mw(a), cb as any); // <-- as any here

const withAB = comp(withA, withB);
// const withAB: Middleware<{  a: number; } & { b: number; }>
```

Here I'm using making `comp` generic in the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of `Middleware<>` type parameter types; so, the call to `comp(withA, withB)` will infer `T` as `[{a: number}, {b: number}]`. The `middlewares` rest parameter is a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) from which `T` can be inferred.  The return type of the function is `MiddleWare<IntersectTuple<T>>`, where `IntersectTuple<T>` takes all the elements of the tuple type `T` and intersects them all together via a technique like that of `UnionToIntersection<T>` as presented [in this question/answer pair](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374908/2887218).

Let's just make sure it works as desired for more than two parameters:

```
const withC: Middleware<{ c: string }> =
  cb => async ev => cb({ ...ev, c: "howdy" });
const composed = comp(withA, withB, withC);
/* const composed: Middleware<{
    a: number;
} & {
    b: number;
} & {
    c: string;
}> */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#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-lMQ31E0r7pR3iHBnzid9kGGKLV4+cwn0+gBud2eqEwhGy7Xev21GUIoSt2WVjQAem7LI90rr8PlG2RSbI6MxapxeKgFYJ7xVWJn0HnhI0reHtX15Mp9SIX3EbOQEWiZgABgASNQNDlwSzIa+3sKWc8urs2VbJFAASXA0EmBAwAoLAdB8TNaHoJgMRAKIAG0AF0aj5dE4J-ZBQGQMoICiNgYHMBCzFqGgzAoNCEMPZAiDYDICTg9VZwQ6g6FIJg+VqYizFAGB8R-SjqIyAYAH5kHQrEGlXMEBy9MYdADKhINY5hPHgpDaj5a1xkVVFTBCZA0Iw5lsNw-CKEI0dtOjcjxGsVMLKjDM-3sQDgNA8CYxqFZtDzcQtIcvAOXuBgsCQDi4DjbJKLDbc+iEYl9RgqIPylTpN1lf0pCbFsh3bOtOyrXt+xrNLfTTVEJ20KcGNXBceiXacNTnAkVg0bcDT3SjaSlNgfA5Lw2D4bdchhfsfWyuF4VyuU+ja3dkH3Tq7SpDkwirfllrgJbTSZEIlvCSIYmQK8byIFaHyfU773PJbrFFGbLT0AxjDMNRbvfKwZvFDch3G2FZVmw0FpJY9T0OgAiMH3w-atBzhfIyuVFlYhURRmskXNdXzHdDQaEkLStbkiDiswwdhNhsmiSGxSrFLRp0NhJgYRtZN+ybazlKbYXyLtuwAKiKyEmwZiAGARjNLSqlc5ysRcltVarpYfOqloQZGFD4KstV57sNCAA)